# Do I need to use PixelRatio with static images in React Native?

Tags: react-native

I read from [PixelRatio](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/pixelratio.html) that I should 'Fetch a correctly sized image' by using PixelRatio. Do I have to do that with static images?
Or will React Native do this for me?

Answer (score 2):

With static images the system will pick the correct one for you based on screen density (pixel ratio), see [Static resources](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image.html#static-resources).

```
<Image source={require('./my-icon.png')} />
```

The docs in `PixelRatio` are related to fetching images from the network. Updated the docs, it was a bit confusing, thanks for pointing it out!